# What is the remedy for memory overflow issue in VMware ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I am using ESXi 4.1. I got following errors often.  I used to delete some of the snapshots i am having and will temporarily solve this issue.

[image]

My datastore shows it has more than 400 GB of free space. But still it occurs. Whether datadisk free information is bogus? What is the root cause for this issue? How to solve this permanently?

Comment: Add more storage? Create fewer virtual machines? Create smaller virtual machines? It seems pretty clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: If you are keeping snapshots for a long amount of time (more than a few days, weeks max), you should rethink that strategy.  Snapshots are not designed for long term use, and eat up a large amount of disk space.

Comment: Which version of ESXi are you running? Before 5, they would incorrectly calculate the provisioned resultant space for VM including snapshots

Comment: @jshin47: Thanks buddy. Comment upvoted

Comment: @Samselvan it might just be that snapshot provisioned space calculation issue. Unfortunately either way you are going to need to free up space by deleting snapshots, or add space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datastore/partition where you store your .vmdk disks is out of space. The message is pretty clear about that. You will need to do one of the following:

1. Extend the partition
2. Delete some virtual guests if you can afford to delete any
3. Delete unused snapshots (these can grow really large over time)

Here's a VMware KB article which may help: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003302

Also check this link for more troubleshooting help: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003564

**UPDATED**: I found a KB with the exact error you're having! Check this out: [NFS datastore with adequate space reports the error: There is no more space for virtual disk](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=2004539&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=294772933&stateId=1%200%20294774843)

Note: I know the related products in the KB show ESXi 5.0, but I got it by searching specifically for ESXi 4.1 KB's, so I think it applies to all ESXi.

Comment: I have added few more clarity to the question buddy.

Comment: Found a VMware KB with the exact error you've got. Check it out, might be your issue.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the root cause for this issue?

The root cause:

Then you buy hardware - and at the end, your virtual machine runs on that - it comes with limited capacity. You can nto fit more than 500gb data on a 500gb hard disc.

Your VM host has run out of space. SImply like that. Hardware upgrade, or thro out garbage, are the only ways to deal with that.